# How do I send a jquery ajax function in js to a node js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I know how to program a jquery ajax function

```js
$.ajax({  
   type:"POST",  
   url:"wwww.nodejsfile.com",
data: id,  
   success:function(data){  

      
      document.getElementById("textarea").value = data;
   }  
});
```

But how would I make it receive the data and send back some info back?

```
nodejs function(data){
//does something with the data
//send back info to js file
}
```

Comment: What node server implementation are you using?

Comment: @Taplar I am using Glitch to host the file

Comment: Implement routing with Express.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a good idea to use ExpressJS for this. The implementation would look something like:

```
// run this in the terminal first:
// $ npm i express

const express = require("express")


const app = express();
app.use(express.json())


app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  //do whatever you want with the body object you received from your client side
  res.send(foo) 
  // to send what you would like back to the frontend, use 
  //res.send(). res.json() instead to send json
})
```

Comment: I believe `app.use(bodyParser.json())` is deprecated in recent versions of Express (4.16). It's been replaced with `express.json()`

Comment: @JeremyThille noted.